# Listen to submit event with two form on same page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, forms, dom-events

I'm creating a Javascript widget that **generate a form**, let's call it `#widget-form` created like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="widget-form">
    <!-- Some inputs -->
</form>
```

I'm **listening** on **submit** event like this:

```
document.getElementById('widget-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    debugger;
}
```

And everything works fine.

BUT, when the widget is present on my Rails app webpage **containing an another form** (generated by `simple_form`), the Javascript is **unable to catch** my `#widget-form` submission event (my Chrome console don't breakpoint on `debugger;`)

*PS: The page just reload when I submit my `#widget-form` form.*

Is there a way to catch this event even if there is another form on the same webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the issue, my bad, **the two forms had the same ID**, and that's why my event wasn't catch by this function.